# How do I change the light bulb in this fan?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan, bulb

I can't figure out how to get into the light fixture on this fan.  There don't appear to be any screws or tabs.  I tried pulling it down gently.  I also tried twisting it gently.  It is possible that it twists or pulls down, but I don't want to damage the fan by applying too much pressure.  How do I change the bulb on this fan?

[image: My fan]

Comment: The styling of that fan looks like a Casa Vieja.  Can you get above it to look down at the top of the motor and see if there's a manufacturer label?

Comment: As I remember it's raise slightly and twist, including both the lens and chrome ring below the lens.

Comment: It's a Harbor Breeze Aero, good thought looking for identifying markings on the top of the motor housing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fan is a Harbor Breeze Aero.  Only the glass comes off.  Slight push up and a twist counter clockwise twists the glass.  Then you let it drop down slowly.  It's about a 1/3 to 1/2 twist to get it to the stopping point.